# Can't resovle a class in jar that already added in my project

Tags: java

[As you can see from the pic, StdOut is a error for can't be resolved. But when I click it with holding Ctrl, I can still open the StdOut.class(Also in pic,you can see it) And StdOut class is in stdlib.jar which is in Referenced Libraries in left of pic. I just want to use StdOut.class. What should I DO?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYX6u.png)

Comment: Is it in a package?

Comment: What do you mean in a package? The 'Example.java' I am working on or what?

Comment: Java classes can reside in a [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html). For example, the class `ArrayList` is in the package `java.util` so to use it, you need to import it. ie `import java.util.ArrayList` and then you can use it. You do not appear to have imported `StdOut`.

Comment: I will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a stupid solution: find the StdOut.class and copy the content from it, make a new package in my project and paste it. Although it's stupid, but this time StdOut.class can be resolved (the Eclipse can resolve my knew package).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jar as an external jar 
BuildPath>>Configure BuildPath >>Libraries>> Add External Jar
Also try importing the full path of StdOut before using it.

Comment: Yes I think I have done that. I right-clicked the project, click Properties, click JAVA Build Path, click Add External JARS, choose the one with StdOut.class in it, and Apply it and finally click OK. But it still not working......When I click StdOut in my program with holding Ctrl , I can open StdOut.class in new page, but Eclipse say it can't be resolved so I still can not use it at all....